# Compiling Java Application on Linux form command line error

Tags: java, linux, compilation

I am a Java newbie, in fact the only reason why I am using it, it's because of lucene.

I used eclipse on Windows to develop a lucene application and worked. So now when I try to compile the application from Linux command-line, it doesn't work.

Here is my folder structure.

```
search_example/
├── lucene-5.0.0
│   ├── analysis
│   │   └── common
│   │       └── lucene-analyzers-common-5.0.0.jar
│   ├── core
│   │   └── lucene-core-5.0.0.jar
│   ├── queries
│   │   └── lucene-queries-5.0.0.jar
│   └── queryparser
│       └── lucene-queryparser-5.0.0.jar
├── lucene_test
│   ├── IndexFiles.java
│   ├── IndexMarkdown.java
│   ├── SearchFiles.java
│   └── SearchMarkdown.java
└── readme.md
```

And here is the compilation call:

```
$ cd ~/search_example
$ javac lucene_test/IndexMarkdown.java -classpath ./; lucene-5.0.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-5.0.0.jar; lucene-5.0.0/core/lucene-core-5.0.0.jar; lucene-5.0.0/queries/lucene-queries-5.0.0.jar ; lucene-5.0.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-5.0.0.jar
```

which I get the following error, indicating that it cannot find the 'jar' files that I passed in as 'classpath'

```
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:20: error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
                                 ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:21: error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
                                          ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:22: error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
                                 ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:23: error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
                                 ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:24: error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
                                 ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:25: error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
                                 ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:26: error: package org.apache.lucene.document does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
                                 ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:27: error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
                              ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:28: error: package org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
                                                ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:29: error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
                              ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:30: error: package org.apache.lucene.index does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
                              ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:31: error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
                              ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:32: error: package org.apache.lucene.store does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
                              ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    private IndexWriter _writer;
            ^
  symbol:   class IndexWriter
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(_indexPathObj);
            ^
  symbol:   class Directory
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(_indexPathObj);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable FSDirectory
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            ^
  symbol:   class Analyzer
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class StandardAnalyzer
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
            ^
  symbol:   class IndexWriterConfig
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
                                        ^
  symbol:   class IndexWriterConfig
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable OpenMode
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
            _writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
                          ^
  symbol:   class IndexWriter
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
      Document doc = new Document();
      ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
      Document doc = new Document();
                         ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
      doc.add(new TextField("category", category, Field.Store.YES));
                  ^
  symbol:   class TextField
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:164: error: package Field does not exist
      doc.add(new TextField("category", category, Field.Store.YES));
                                                       ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
      doc.add(new StringField("subject", subject, Field.Store.YES));
                  ^
  symbol:   class StringField
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:165: error: package Field does not exist
      doc.add(new StringField("subject", subject, Field.Store.YES));
                                                       ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
      doc.add(new LongField("modified", lastModified, Field.Store.NO));
                  ^
  symbol:   class LongField
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:175: error: package Field does not exist
      doc.add(new LongField("modified", lastModified, Field.Store.NO));
                                                           ^
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:181: error: cannot find symbol
      doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
                  ^
  symbol:   class TextField
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:184: error: cannot find symbol
      if (_writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) 
                                               ^
  symbol:   variable OpenMode
  location: class IndexFiles
./lucene_test/IndexFiles.java:195: error: cannot find symbol
        _writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), doc);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Term
  location: class IndexFiles
```

## UPDATE:

Since I was compiling on a Linux OS, multiple directories in `classpath` should've been separated with a colon(:) not a semi-colon(;). So here is the new complication code which also I included the full path of the `jar` files, but it still cannot find the classes defined in those jar files.

```
javac -classpath ~/search_example/lucene-5.0.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-5.0.0.jar:~/search_example/lucene-5.0.0/core/lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:~/search_example/lucene-5.0.0/queries/lucene-queries-5.0.0.jar:~/search_example/lucene-5.0.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-5.0.0.jar lucene_test/*.java
```

Comment: try it with maven or gradle or  On Unix, we would do this:

javac -classpath dir1:dir2:dir3 ...

whereas on Windows we have:

javac -classpath dir1;dir2;dir3 ..

Comment: don't I need to specify the jar1:jar2 with classpath? This seems like a very easy project to compile without the need of a 3rd party build management tool, so if I can I would like to avoid using one.

Comment: try suggestions from here http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Comment: is it because you have spaces between the jar file entries in your classpath  ?

Comment: @learningJava Thanks for the link, it's exactly what I need

Comment: @RuntimeException, no I tried removing spaces, it's unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to give full path to your classpath vars or atleast proper reference from your current directory.

However, its always good to use a build tool like maven which helps to get around dependencies and classpaths.

Comment: the full path didn't fix the issue, and I would really like to avoid using third party tools for one off compilation projects. If I were developing something bigger I would definitely use a build tool like Maven,